# Pgfplot second intersection point

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

As it can be seen in the figure i added a line from the first intersection (y=2x and y=6-x) to x(2). But i couldn't add a line from second intersection (y=x and y=6-x) to x(3). i tried `intersection-2` but it gave an error. **i want to make this using intersection command** because there may be new situations in which i can't find the intersection exactly.

What should i do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
         height=7cm, width=7cm,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                enlargelimits,
                ytick=\empty,
                xtick={2,3},          
    every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
    every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}],
    \addplot[name path=f,blue,domain={0:2}] {2*x} node[pos=.8, above]{};
    \addplot[name path=h,blue,domain={2:3}] {6-x} node[pos=.8, above,,rotate=-15]{};
    \addplot[name path=g,blue,domain={0:3}] {x} node[pos=.8, below,rotate=30]{};
    \addplot[name path=bos,white,domain={2:4}] {x/2} node[pos=.8, below,rotate=30]{};

    \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=f and g, soft clip={domain=0:2}];
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=h and g, soft clip={domain=2:3}];
    \node[coordinate,pin=95:{\footnotesize{$y=2x$}}] at (axis cs:1,2){};
    \node[coordinate,pin=-45:\footnotesize{$y=x$}] at (axis cs:0.8,0.8){};
    \node[coordinate,pin=40:\footnotesize{$y=6-x$}] at (axis cs:2.5,3.5){};
    \draw [name intersections={of=f and h},ultra thin,gray] ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- (intersection-1);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: They only intersect at one point.

Comment: right but how to add. i tried intersection-1 as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compute the intersections independently to use them in the same path. Otherwise you can use the `name intersections` on each path with different path names.

One option is to use different name prefixes.

**EDIT** About problems;

1. You are intersecting the lines at their endpoints and this causes numerical instabilities. Your redundant path named `boş` causes the figures drawn smaller and that shrinks the paths. Instead you can increase the domain of lines slightly to ensure a proper intersection.
2. In order to extend the axis you can use `xmax` key instead as I did below. Or you can use `clip=false` if you need that node to be printed
3. If you don't want to draw anything, instead of `white` use `draw=none`.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
     height=7cm, width=7cm,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick={2,3},xmax=4,% <---Added xmax instead 
every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}],
\addplot[name path=f,blue,domain={0:2}] {2*x} node[pos=.8, above]{};
\addplot[name path=h,blue,domain={2:3.005}] {6-x} node[pos=.8, above,,rotate=-15]{};
\addplot[name path=g,blue,domain={0:3.005}] {x}   node[pos=.8, below,rotate=30]{};
%\addplot[name path=bos,draw=none,domain={2:4}] {x/2} node[pos=.8, below,rotate=30]{};

\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=f and g, soft clip={domain=0:2}];
\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=h and g, soft clip={domain=2:3}];
\node[coordinate,pin=95:{\footnotesize{$y=2x$}}] at (axis cs:1,2){};
\node[coordinate,pin=-45:\footnotesize{$y=x$}] at (axis cs:0.8,0.8){};
\node[coordinate,pin=40:\footnotesize{$y=6-x$}] at (axis cs:2.5,3.5){};
\draw [name intersections={of=f and h,name=fh},
       name intersections={of=h and g,name=hg},
       ultra thin,gray] 
       (hg-1) -- (axis cs:3,0)
       (fh-1) -- (axis cs:2,0)
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry. i added `\draw [name intersections={of=f and h,name ...` to my original code but it gave an error that is **No shape named hg-1 is known.** . where is the problem?

Comment: @mert whatever you put in the `name=`, it becomes the prefix. If you said `fh` you need to use `fh-1`

Comment: i copied what you write and pasted. it is just as you write but it is still giving error.

Comment: i deleted `\draw [name intersections={of=f and h},ultra thin,gray] ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- (intersection-1);` and added `\draw [name intersections={of=f and h,name=fh},
           name intersections={of=h and g,name=hg},
           ultra thin,gray] 
           (hg-1) -- (axis cs:3,0)
           (fh-1) -- (axis cs:2,0)
        ;`

Comment: @mert That's strange. Do you completely copy paste the whole code in a separate document? It should work I guess. I don't have a special TeX distro.

Comment: Yes your code work if completely copied but why doesn't it work in my code, i need all my stuff: nodes, patterns...

Comment: @mert I think you are making a tiny change somewhere. I'll use your code in a minute

Comment: @mert Rica ederim, gene bekleriz.